# Antes de mais nada

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

Sempre usei a expressão **antes de mais nada** com seu sentido habitual, sinônimo de **em primeiro lugar**, sem procurar lógica ou falta de lógica nela.

Hoje, uma pessoa para quem o portugês é uma língua estrangeira, que desconhecia a espressão e a que ouviu pela primeira vez questionou-me sobre sua lógica. Faz sentido seu argumento.

Em uma série (de eventos, ou de coisas a falar), o primeiro evento vem antes de todos os demais. Nada o antecede. Não vem depois de nada. Para nos referirmos ao primeiro evento, poderíamos dizer **depois de mais nada**. Já o último vem depois de todos os demais e, portanto, antes de mais nada. Seguindo essa lógica, **antes de mais nada** deveria se referir ao último evento, não ao primeiro.

Gostaria, por gentileza, de ouvir os comentários dessa comunidade sobre a análise acima proposta, sobre a etimologia da expressão **antes de mais nada**, e sobre a eventual existência da expressão **depois de mais nada**.

Comment: @Schilive, sobre '"nada" pode significar "alguma coisa"', pode mesmo? Sem querer contrariar um respeitável dicionário como o Houaiss, o Aurélio não registra esse significado. Em português, a dupla negação é utilizada para reforçar a negação. Pergunto-me se o significado proposto do Houaiss não estaria apenas documentando o uso de "nada" na dupla negação.

Comment: O "nada" é muito especial... :) Uma resposta absolutamente zelosa explicaria coisas como «não comi nada», que significa na verdade o oposto do que diz: que «comi nada», isto é, que «não comi»; e não que «comi não-nada», isto é, que «comi alguma coisa».

Comment: A expressão não é exclusiva da língua portuguesa. Aqui pode ver diferentes contextos em que é usado o equivalente inglês "before anything else" (que, por vezes, também é usado com o significado de "em primeiro lugar"): https://context.reverso.net/traducao/ingles-portugues/before+anything+else)

Answer (score 4):

Línguas naturais (em oposição às artificiais), são definidas pelo uso, não pela coerência lógica. Sobre a expressão "depois de mais nada", duvido muito que alguém a entendesse com o significado de "primeiramente". Dentre seus poucos usos que encontro, ela tem valor literal, [como em](https://entretenimento.uol.com.br/noticias/redacao/2020/03/30/djonga-fala-de-pandemia-se-a-gente-nao-mudar-depois-disso-nao-muda-mais.htm): "Se a gente não mudar depois disso daí [a pandemia de covid-19], a gente não muda depois de mais nada"

A expressão "antes de mais nada" é consagrada — de uso corrente, já [foi usada](https://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/antes-de-mais-nada-cuidado-com-os-sabichoes/) por Camilo Castelo Branco (séc. XIX), Machado de Assis, Rui Barbosa, Carlos Drummond de Andrade e Clarice Lispector.

Sobre sua origem histórica não encontrei nada específico, mas vale notar que [há também](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/antes-do-mais/5910) a expressão, equivalente, "antes do/de mais", onde "mais" [significa](https://www.aulete.com.br/mais) "resto", "os outros" (e também já ouvi "antes de qualquer outra coisa"). Sobre o papel do "nada", uma possibilidade talvez seja ênfase, mas normalmente ele [pode ser usado](https://dicionario.priberam.org/nada) para enfatizar apenas negações, então ele estaria aqui ou por erro arraigado, ou enfatizando uma negação na sua origem e/ou implícita na expressão (algo como "não falo mais nada, antes de") — mas isso não passa de especulação.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de mais nada, note-se que construções linguísticas não são necessariamente lógicas ([EIDT COLLING, 2020](https://revistas.ufpr.br/revistax/article/view/76899)).

Sobre a expressão em questão, há quem sugira a alternativa "**antes de tudo**" ([Recanto das Letras](https://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/2369155)).

Pessoalmente, como falante nativo de português brasileiro, a opção "**depois de mais nada**" me causa muito estranhamento.